# How I can use 'OR' in my db queries

Tags: mysql, sql, database, drupal, drupal-7

What i really want is :

```
$query = db_select('watchdog', 'wa');
$query->orderBy('wa.timestamp', 'DESC')
        ->condition('blablabla', 'closed', '=') or 
          ('blablabla', 'blabla', '=')
           or ('blablabla', 'balblabla', '=')
        ->range(0, 20);
  $result = $query->execute();
```

I want to put many conditions with or but i do not know how to write them down..

Comment: Try my answer, and let me know is it working or not.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  its belongs to [drupal.stackexchange.com](http://drupal.stackexchange.com) site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default is set to AND, to use or, you have to do like that

```
  $query = db_select('watchdog', 'wa');
    $query->orderBy('wa.timestamp', 'DESC');
    $or = db_or();
    $or->condition('blablabla', 'closed', '=');
    $or->condition('blablabla', 'blabla', '=');
    $or->condition('blablabla', 'balblabla', '=');
    $query->condition($or);
    $query->range(0, 20);

    $result = $query->execute();
```

Comment: could you tell me how to do this in my code?

Comment: edited to fit what you need

Comment: and the db_select and range? How they will shown?

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = db_select('watchdog', 'wa');
//your condition
$condition = db_or()
  ->condition('blablabla', 'closed', '=')
  ->condition('blablabla', 'blabla', '=')
  ->condition('blablabla', 'balblabla', '=');

$query->condition($condition)
      ->orderBy('wa.timestamp', 'DESC')
      ->range(0, 20);
$result = $query->execute();
```

Try the above code.

Comment: It works but the first answer was faster... : /